# square Matrix transpose with CUDA

Tags: matrix, cuda

I'm trying to write  the  matrix transpose algorithm. I test this program with matrix size equal to 1024, the result shows that not all elements are in the right places.

Why isn't my array transposing correctly? Does anyone can help me or give me any hint? I will appreciate it. Thanks a lot!

there is the whole cpu code:

```
__global__ void transpose_naive (float *out, float *in, int w, int h )
{
    unsigned int xIdx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int yIdx = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    if ( xIdx <=w && yIdx <=h ) {
        unsigned int idx_in = xIdx + w * yIdx;
        unsigned int idx_out = yIdx + h * xIdx;
        out[idx_out] = in[idx_in];
    }
}

int main()

{
    int nx=1024;
    int mem_size = nx*nx*sizeof(float);
    int t=32;
    dim3 dimGrid(((nx-1)/t) +1, ((nx-1)/t) +1);
    dim3 dimBlock(t,t);

    float *h_idata = (float*)malloc(mem_size);
    float *h_cdata = (float*)malloc(mem_size);
    float *d_idata, *d_cdata;
    checkCuda(cudaMalloc(&d_idata, mem_size) );
    checkCuda(cudaMalloc(&d_cdata, mem_size) );   
    // host
    for (int j = 0; j < nx; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
            h_idata[j*nx + i] = j*nx + i;

    // device
    checkCuda(cudaMemcpy(d_idata, h_idata, mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    // events for timing
    cudaEvent_t startEvent, stopEvent;
    checkCuda(cudaEventCreate(&startEvent) );
    checkCuda(cudaEventCreate(&stopEvent) );
    float ms;
    checkCuda( cudaEventRecord(startEvent, 0) );
    transpose_naive<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_cdata, d_idata,nx,nx);
    checkCuda(cudaEventRecord(stopEvent, 0) );
    checkCuda(cudaEventSynchronize(stopEvent) );
    checkCuda(cudaEventElapsedTime(&ms, startEvent, stopEvent) );
    checkCuda( cudaMemcpy(h_cdata, d_cdata, mem_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    printf("the time %5f ", ms);
    printf("\n");
    savetofile(h_idata,"i.txt",nx,nx);
    savetofile(h_cdata,"t.txt",nx,nx);

error_exit:
    // cleanup
    checkCuda(cudaEventDestroy(startEvent) );
    checkCuda(cudaEventDestroy(stopEvent) );
    checkCuda( cudaFree(d_cdata) );
    checkCuda( cudaFree(d_idata) );
    free(h_idata);
    free(h_cdata);
    system("pause"); 
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe show what exactly is wrong with the result? E.g. a small example. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the condition in the kernel should be `if ( xIdx < w && yIdx < h ) {...` because indices start at 0.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is something wrong with file output "i.txt" and "t.txt" otherwise the program looks to be correct. I have made some minor changes in your code by adding error checking and printing on the standard output stream. I am printing the last (1020 - 1024) 3 x 3 matrix to cross check the transpose. Run it on your system and verify whether the matrix transpose is correct or not?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
if (code != cudaSuccess)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),file, line);
    if (abort) exit(code);
}
}

__global__ void transpose_naive(float *out, float *in, int w, int h)
{
unsigned int xIdx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
unsigned int yIdx = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

if (xIdx <= w && yIdx <= h) {
    unsigned int idx_in = xIdx + w * yIdx;
    unsigned int idx_out = yIdx + h * xIdx;
    out[idx_out] = in[idx_in];
}
}

int main()

{
int nx = 1024;
int mem_size = nx*nx*sizeof(float);
int t = 32;
dim3 dimGrid(((nx - 1) / t) + 1, (((nx - 1) / t) + 1));
dim3 dimBlock(t, t);

float *h_idata = (float*)malloc(mem_size);
float *h_cdata = (float*)malloc(mem_size);
float *d_idata, *d_cdata;
gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_idata, mem_size));
gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_cdata, mem_size));
// host
for (int j = 0; j < nx; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
        h_idata[j*nx + i] = j*nx + i;

// device
gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_idata,h_idata,mem_size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

// events for timing
cudaEvent_t startEvent, stopEvent;
gpuErrchk(cudaEventCreate(&startEvent));
gpuErrchk(cudaEventCreate(&stopEvent));
float ms;
gpuErrchk(cudaEventRecord(startEvent, 0));
transpose_naive << <dimGrid, dimBlock >> >(d_cdata, d_idata, nx, nx);
gpuErrchk(cudaEventRecord(stopEvent, 0));
gpuErrchk(cudaEventSynchronize(stopEvent));
gpuErrchk(cudaEventElapsedTime(&ms, startEvent, stopEvent));
gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_cdata,d_cdata,mem_size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

printf("the time %5f ", ms);
printf("\n");
for (int i = 1020; i < 1024; i++) {
    for (int j = 1020; j < 1024; j++) {
    printf("%.2f ", h_idata[i*nx + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
}

printf("\n");
for (int i = 1020; i < 1024; i++) {
    for (int j = 1020; j < 1024; j++) {
        printf("%.2f ", h_cdata[i*nx + j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
//savetofile(h_idata, "i.txt", nx, nx);
//savetofile(h_cdata, "t.txt", nx, nx);
//error_exit:
// cleanup
gpuErrchk(cudaEventDestroy(startEvent));
gpuErrchk(cudaEventDestroy(stopEvent));
gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_cdata));
gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_idata));
free(h_idata);
free(h_cdata);
//system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only flaw in the code is the incorrect bound checks in the following line of the kernel.

```
if ( xIdx <=w && yIdx <=h ) {
```

As the indices are from `0` to `w-1` and `0` to `h-1` for x and y dimensions respectively, the `if` condition should be as  follows:

```
if ( xIdx <w && yIdx <h ) {
```

Comment: even I changed this condition, if I test the program for N <1024, it is working well but if I test for N = 1024 the results are incorrect. the elements of the resulting matrix takes values that are not presented in the initial matrix. for example the value 1.020 e 006 that does not exist in the matrix